# Does a repeated download protect against file corruption?

Tags: file-corruption, hashing, checksum, data-integrity

**Disclosed real issue:**
I use a program called youtube-dl to download and archive videos from websites like YouTube and Twitch. To verify the integrity of the downloads, I download the same video twice and verify that their checksums match. My worry is that some unnoticed issue may cause both videos to be silently corrupted in the same way, resulting in matching checksums even though their data integrity has been compromised.

**Originally posted question:**
Can specific data corruption be reproducible down to its resulting hash value?

For example, if a file experienced data corruption after executing it due to some underlying software or hardware issue, could a copy of that file experience the exact same manner of data corruption after a similar execution, resulting in a hash value that matches the value of the original corrupt file?

In other words, is all data corruption necessarily unique in some way, or can some corruption be consistent and replicated exactly?

Comment: This question is not specific at all and the phrases care confusing. I never executed files - only programs. And this execution triggers reading of the program file. Therefore there is no corruption with a executed program because programs typically are not self-modifying. Unless your hardware does not rewrite the program file there is no "hardware issue".  "Software issue" and "hardware issue" are not specific enough in your description. Your description sounds to me as if you have something to hide.

Comment: @r2d3 I have nothing to hide. I apologize as I'm not very good at phrasing. Please bear with me. Until now I believed that all factors that could cause a file to be corrupted are necessarily random, as in all possible corruptions produce unique results every time in the file's data. My question arose when I found a Wikipedia page entitled "File Verification" whose summary mentions how comparing two copies of the same file bit-by-bit to verify data integrity "may miss systematic corruptions which might occur to both files." I'm not sure what "systematic corruptions" is referring to and...

Comment: @r2d3 ...wondered if that meant that two copies of the same file can be corrupted in the exact same manner, resulting in their data still matching each other post-corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, yes. In practice it's a lot harder.

A great number of factors are in play when a file is being created, from electricity to typos. To create a consistent corruption you need to control every single factor, and that's basically possible only in tightly controlled lab environments. In that situation it's possible to consistently create an identical string of bits which would produce an identical hash.

So if you're for example downloading a file somewhere, every file hash matches and every one of them is corrupt, the corruption is most likely in the original file. The site might show a hash value for you to validate the download, but that's not necessarily the hash value of the available file; the original was hashed before it was ever uploaded to the location, and that value is presented to the visitors for verification. The creators wouldn't even know that the uploaded file is somehow corrupt until someone told them :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believed until now that file corruption cannot be replicated exactly unless every factor was controlled like you described. What drove me to ask my question was coming across [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_verification) which states that comparing two copies of the same file bit-by-bit "may miss systematic corruptions which might occur to both files." I wondered if that meant two copies of the same file can be corrupted in the exact same manner, resulting in their data still matching each other post-corruption.

Comment: That's a bit confusing statement indeed. Full disclosure - I'm not an expert, but I many times many moons ago I asked the exact same question from a guy who is. He spoke a lot longer, my answer's what I remember from that conversation. A decade and a half tends to have an effect on info you don't need to apply in practice on even yearly basis :-)

Answer (score 0):

> @r2d3 ...wondered if that meant that two copies of the same file can be corrupted in the exact same manner, resulting in their data still matching each other post-corruption.

Uri, if have a virus in a system who implants himself into every executable file I expect him to manipulate two identical files the same way, giving two identical manipulated files as an output.  Comparing both manipulated files will not show any difference. When using cryptographic hashs the attacker has to know that the second file is a hash and the attacker would be forced to rewrite a new hash corresponding to the manipulated file.

Once you put salt in front of your hash and encrypt the chain of (salt + hash) an attacker cannot manipulate your hash anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that something can maliciously manipulate two files to have matching hashes. What I'm wondering is if it's possible for matching hashes to happen unintentionally. For example, if a bug occurs that causes a file to be corrupted, resulting in a new hash value, and that same bug occurs to an exact copy of the original non-corrupt file, corrupting that copy as well, is there a possibility that both corrupt files would have the same hash value?

Comment: I expect both output files to be identical unless there is no current date and/or time information put into the file data.

Comment: Is there any significant likelihood of the scenario I described actually happening? Would you agree with the answer that Peregrino69 gave me, that purposely recreating that scenario would only be possible in a tightly-controlled lab environment? @r2d3

Comment: I would recommend you to move from theoretical academical questions to the real reason you are asking these strange questions. Data corruption happens accidentally or on purpose. Corruption can happen at different levels. There are recipes how to deal with corruption like using ECC-Ram, checksums or backups.

Comment: Ok, the real reason I'm asking this is because I use a program called `youtube-dl` to download and archive videos from websites like YouTube and Twitch. To verify the integrity of the downloads, I download the same video twice and verify that their checksums match. My worry is that some unnoticed issue may cause both videos to be silently corrupted in the same way, resulting in matching checksums even though their data integrity has been compromised. I'm probably being paranoid, but my brain won't shut up about this. Sorry for beating around the bush earlier. @r2d3

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I suspect right from the beginning. You could have made lots of people life easier but just explaining your problem! I will update my answer now!

Answer (score 0):

After the disclosure of the real issue behind a highly theoretical question my answer changes as well:

As Youtube does not provide hashs for the videos on its site even a repeated download cannot protect you against data corruption.

Furthermore there is no mechanism established that enables you to upload a hash you generated in order to verify the integrity of a download.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for editing my question. I apologize for causing so much confusion and trouble. I understand that YouTube's videos don't have hashes, so there's no guarantee that the video's data hasn't been altered on any of their servers I'm downloading from. But assuming the video is fine, would a repeated download reveal any corruption caused by something on my end? Could a software or hardware issue on my end cause a video to be corrupted in the same manner every time it's downloaded, resulting in the same hash no matter how many times it's downloaded?